# Laravel: redirect from controller to named route with params in URL

Tags: php, laravel

how can I redirect from my controller to a named route and include variables in the URL, e.g.

```
return Redirect::to('admin/articles/create/'.$article_type.'/'.$area_id.'/'.$area_type);
```

this works, but I think that I missed a shortcut or something?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In Laravel 5, you can use the helper methods:

```
return redirect()->route('route.name', [$param]);
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use `Redirect::route()` to redirect to a named route and pass an array of parameters as the second argument

```
 Redirect::route('route.name',array('param1' => $param1,'param2' => $param2))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

In **Laravel 9** you can use the `to_route()` helper function.

```php
return to_route('route.name', [$param]);
```

Comment: Okey... i have never seen this helper.... but it works for me

Answer (score 6):

You can try this :

```
return redirect()->route('profile', [$user]);
```

This can help also if you are trying to redirect user to a profile with the `id`.