# Laravel session flash message appears multiple times on pageback

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, session-state

In my controller:

```
 Session::flash('created', "Student created");
 return Redirect::to('student');
```

In my view:

```
 @if(Session::has('created'))
 alert('updated');
 @endif
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Why you are using session for? You can use Redirect::route() method as better solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me, instead of using `Session::get('key')`, I use `Session::pull('key')` and it only popup a single time.

E.g

```php
@if(Session::has('success'))
    {{ Session::pull('success') }} 
@endif
```

---

According to [Laravel 7.x doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#storing-data)

> The pull method will retrieve and delete an item from the session in a single statement:

Answer (score 0):

Display session message

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable alert-box">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    {{ Session::get('success') }}               
  </div>
@endif
@if(Session::has('error'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable alert-box">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    {{ Session::get('error') }} 
  </div>
@endif
```

Called from controller

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data added successfully');
```

Comment: alert shows multiple time when i press back and forth button in browesr

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid the unnecessary use of session. You can use [Redirect::route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079280/laravel-redirect-from-controller-to-named-route-with-prams-in-url). Check below example:

1) Initialize `$strChecked = false;` into your student route controller and then set `$strChecked = true;` into you student update method.

2) Replace your return line with `return \Redirect::route('student')->with('strChecked', $strChecked);`

3) Then in your view, you can use:

```
@if($strChecked)
    alert('updated');
@endif
```

**EDITS:**

Let me illustrate with my working demo code:

**1) ROUTE:**

```
Route::get('flash', 'FlashController@flashIndex')->name('frontend.flash');
Route::post('flash/update', 'FlashController@studentUpdate')->name('frontend.flash.update');
```

**2) VIEW:**

```
@section('content')
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'frontend.flash.update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}

{{ Form::submit('Demo', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'margin-right:15px']) }}  

{{ Form::close() }}

@endsection
@section('after-scripts-end')
    <script>
        @if(Session::has('created'))
         alert('updated');
        @endif
    </script>
@stop
```

**3) CONTROLLER:**

```
//Method to display action...
public function flashIndex()
{
 return view('frontend.flash');  
}

//Method to update action...
public function studentUpdate()
{
 Session::flash('created', "Student created");
 return Redirect::to('flash'); 
}
```

Hope this clears your doubts.

Above example working fine at my end. Describe your code if this is not work for you.

Comment: Sorry not workoing ,not able to get $strChecked value at view.

Comment: Please specify which error you are facing with this code?

Comment: $strChecked value undefined because its written inside jquery or user anywhere in page it shows undefined

Comment: Got the point, may be you are not focused on point 1). You need to pass `$strChecked` to initial view time(i.e. your method which initialize this view). Update your question in detail so we can sort it out.

Comment: sorry its still not working for me isn't there any other way to flash alert ? and the code is just as above im not able to get 

@if($strChecked)
    alert('updated');
@endif

is shows  $strChecked undefined.

Comment: its not working for me ,any other way to forget session variable ? i user forget method but it 's not working.